QTreeWidget internal move rows (only topLevelItems)
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.treeWidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.treeWidget.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.treeWidget.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.treeWidget.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.treeWidget.setObjectName("treeWidget")
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
        item_1 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(item_0)
        item_1 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(item_0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.treeWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Column 1"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Column 2"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.treeWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.treeWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Data 1.1"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Data 1.2"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Data 2.1"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Data 2.2"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(2).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Data 3.1"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(2).setText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Data 3.2"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(3).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Data 4.1"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(3).setText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Data 4.2"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(3).child(0).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Data 4.1.1"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(3).child(0).setText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Data 4.1.2"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(3).child(1).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Data 4.2.1"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(3).child(1).setText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Data 4.2.2"))
        self.treeWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

The above example works: I have a QTreeWidget which i can drag and drop items internal.
But:

I want to drag and drop only toplevelitems
As for 1. i don't want to drop as a child in another QTreeWidgetItem
I want to notify somehow when a move is made to change some Apendix index number in one column of tree widget and for save to changes to sqlite3 db file.

Is this possible?
Edit: Maybe this will be helpful
This code seems to work:
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setFlags(self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).flags() & ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled)
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setFlags(self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).flags() & ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled)
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(2).setFlags(self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(2).flags() & ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled)
        
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(3).child(0).setFlags(self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(3).child(0).flags() & ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled & ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled)
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(3).child(1).setFlags(self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(3).child(1).flags() & ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled & ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled)


As for three, maybe a reimplementation of dropEvent is required.

With 1 do you mean that you only want to change the order of top level items?

Yes like a simple QTableWidget.

Then unsetting the ItemIsDropEnabled for the whole model. You should probably create a recursive function which automatically navigates the tree, instead of those ridiculously long lines. Remember that you should only ask one question per post, so, since you've already found out how to solve the first part of the problem, edit your question, remove that (you shouldn't put answers in questions anyway) and focus on the one you're missing, also clarifying exactly what you expect to change during the movement (what is "Appendix index number"?)
